# ¿Qué significa "TAM" cuando se combina con otra palabra?

Tags: vocabulario

hay muchas palabras en español que empiezan con "tam".

Por ejemplo, "Tambien" y "Tampoco".

¿Qué significa "TAM" cuando se combina con otra palabra?

¿Puede proporcionar al menos tres ejemplos con palabras compuestas cuyo prefijo sea "tam"?

Answer (score 4):

Ese prefijo TAM en realidad es el prefijo  [**tan<sup>3</sup>**](https://dle.rae.es/tan) (apocope de **tanto**):

en que cambia la *n* por *m* por ir delante de *b* o *p*. Por ejemplo, [también](https://dle.rae.es/tambi%C3%A9n?).

Pero en la mayoría de las palabras que empiezan por **tam**, este no es un prefijo, sino parte de la propia palabra.

Comment: ___Tamaño___ es similar en su origen a _también_ y _tampoco_. Deriva del latín _TAM MAGNUS_, o sea "tan grande".